# Compound referencing with achemso

Tags: cross-referencing, achemso

I would like to reference the compounds in my schemes with `achemso` in a manner similar to the options given by `chemstyle`, but is that possible?
The documentation for `achemso` list a `scheme` environment but the `\schemref` macro fails

Answer (score 1):

The `scheme` environment has really nothing to do with `\schemeref`: the naming in `chemstyle` is just because of the likely use case. In particular, the way that `\schemeref` works is by using the `psfrag` package to do search-and-replace in EPS figures.

For `achemso`, the class is about submission to the ACS. They will need 'final' graphics (they don't use LaTeX for the journal itself) so this kind of auto-replacement is inappropriate. For the `achemso` package, the code is pretty minimal and you can load `chemstyle` as well should you wish.